# Is there a printable character which is not available for use in SMS messages?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, utf, telecommunication

I need a printable character which is not available in the mobile SMS messages. The reason is that I have a file which has a bunch of data, and one of those data fields is SMS-text. It is dummy data ofcourse.

I need to extract this field. The tool I am using for it asks for a **field-separator**, on the basis of which it separates fields into a CSV file. And it uses a comma character as the default field separator.

Now the problem is that whenever a comma character occurs in SMS text, it separates the rest of the SMS text and makes it a separate field.

**So my question is that how do I find a *single* character which I can use as a field separater in this case?**

Comment: The CSV file format has a way so you can embed field delimiters as characters within fields: quote the field. `"foo, bar",42,baz,"another,comma"`. That is the proper way to do it, don't look for characters which may not be in use.

Comment: @deceze Tried that. Then whenever a `"` occurs in the text of the SMS, it considers the rest of it as a separate field

Comment: Not if you parse the CSV properly with a proper CSV parser…!?

Comment: @deceze Really? Can you givve me an example of a proper CSV parser? Because I am wonder how any parser would know if the `"` is the enclosing `"` or a part of the SMS text somebody typed.

Comment: Of course there's a way to escape `"` inside of `"` so you can use `"` *and* `,` as part of the string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules. You just need to *encode* it properly and then *parse* it properly.

Comment: @deceze Hey I have no control over the input data. The SMS messages come as they are, with embedded double quotes. The input is in `pcap` format. I am using `tshark` utility to extract fields from it and export into the csv format. If I had control over input, I would sanitize it by removing problematic characters

Comment: So the input is in a format which cannot be parsed unambiguously…?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can encode the text using Base64 before sending SMS, and then decode after receiving. Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [GSM charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) spec. Be aware about the 7bits / 8bits encoding and the encoding of the different (human) languages.